# javascript alertMessage recurse infinitely,and can only end by throwing an exception

Tags: javascript, function, intellij-idea, tooltip

why   alertMessage  show  this tips in intelliJ?

[image]

Comment: can you show us whats in the function? I'm guess you call it in there

Comment: Can you attach you code please.

Comment: Please post the code.  Your image has the tooltip covering the body of the function.  No one can help you if we can't see the code.

Answer (score 1):

Well you are calling the same method inside of it so it keeps calling

```
function alertMessage(message) {
    alertMessage(......)  <-- calls itself so it keeps looping
}
```

did you mean to call `alert()`?

(You can see the l t and M under the tooltip popping up from behind the tooltip)